# How to validate and insert new random value if it is present in database

Tags: php

This is my code

```
$lclReferCode = rand(100000,999999);

function random(){
   $lclReferCode1 = rand(100000,999999);
   return $lclReferCode1;
}

$lclReferCode = random();
$lclQuery = "SELECT * FROM `sign_up` WHERE us_refer_code = '$lclReferCode'";

$qryResult = mysql_query($lclQuery);

if(mysql_num_rows($qryResult) == 0){

$lclQuery = "INSERT INTO sign_up(us_refer_code) values('" . $lclReferCode . "')";


            $qryResult = mysql_query($lclQuery);

            }else{

              random();
             }
```

Here my intention is to insert unique values not the duplicates. Before inserting I am checking the database if this random number is present already or not if it is present I have to generate new values again I have to generate values and match if not present then the insert query executes. can anyone help me.

Comment: make the field unique, and then catch the duplicate error and recall the function, faster then doing a select.  Besides if you can have the value only once is it not unique then?  But mysql_ is deprecated, so I would do it in PDO, with error mode exception.  I would also get rid of that concatenating of variables into my sql.for SQL Injection reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Like this (untested):

```
function setRandom(\PDO $PDO){
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `sign_up` WHERE us_refer_code = :us_refer_code");
    try{
        $stmt->execute([':us_refer_code' => rand(100000,999999)]);
    }catch(\PDOException $e){
        if($e->getCode() == 23000){ //if I recall right this is duplicate key
            setRandom($PDO); //<-- recursive.
        }else{
            //if not duplicate key re-throw the error.
            throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
    }
}
```

But you have to use PDO, with the error mode set to exception, and with the database field defined as a unique index.

It might not be a bad idea to build in a recursion limit, as you could get in a situation where it never finds a value not entered in the DB.  That would look like this.

```
function setRandom(\PDO $PDO, $limit=0){
    if($limit > 1000) throw new \Exception(__FUNCTION__.' recursion limit exceeded');
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `sign_up` WHERE us_refer_code = :us_refer_code");
    try{
        $stmt->execute([':us_refer_code' => rand(100000,999999)]);
    }catch(\PDOException $e){
        if($e->getCode() == 23000){ //if I recall right this is duplicate key
            setRandom($PDO, ++$limit);//<-- recursive
        }else{
            //if not duplicate key re-throw the error.
            throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
    }
}
```

This would give it 1000 tries before throwing an exception.  It's never good to have code that has a real possibility of creating infinite recursion.

On my sites I have a error handler that shoots me an email if I have any uncaught exceptions.  So I would know right away.  Of coarse this is optional and some of this is tightly coupled to your particular use case.

Otherwise you will have to use a select inside of a while loop. like this (Also untested).

```
/**
*  return false or the random value to use.
* @return false|int 
*/
function ckRandom($lclReferCode){
    $lclReferCode = rand(100000,999999);
    $lclQuery = "SELECT * FROM `sign_up` WHERE us_refer_code = '$lclReferCode'";
    $qryResult = mysql_query($lclQuery);
    if(mysql_num_rows($qryResult) == 0){
        //no result means the number is not used yet.
        return $lclReferCode;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

//$limit = 0;
$lclReferCode = false;
while( false === $lclReferCode){
    $lclReferCode = ckRandom();
    //if($limt > 1000) throw new \Exception(' recursion limit exceeded');
    //++$limit;
}
//if $lclReferCode IS NOT false then it is the last random number searched that had no results in the DB
$lclQuery = "INSERT INTO sign_up(us_refer_code) values('" . $lclReferCode . "')";
```

See the idea is the while loop will trap execution until the result returns something other then 0, if it's 0 then no row exists. (you have this backwards).

And again, this is prone to infinite recursion.  I added the "limit" stuff in comments.

That said, I would strongly suggest doing away with any `mysql_` functions as they wont work post PHP7.

Answer (score 0):

you need to try like this

```
function random(){
   $lclReferCode = rand(100000,999999);
   $lclQuery = "SELECT * FROM `sign_up` WHERE us_refer_code = '$lclReferCode'";
   $qryResult = mysql_query($lclQuery);
   $checkRow=mysql_num_rows($qryResult);
   if ($checkRow>0) {
        return random();
   }else{
        $lclQuery = "INSERT INTO sign_up(us_refer_code) values('" . $lclReferCode . "')";
        $qryResult = mysql_query($lclQuery);
        return true;
    }
}

if (random()===true) {
    echo 'inserted succesfully';
}
```

remember this is demonstration.i recommend to you use `mysqli` or `pdo` because `mysql`  is not valid in `php7`

Comment: should i call this function before function as random();

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix if i use if condition then it will call random.if row is 0.With the recursive call to random otherwise condition will be true .why if condition will not work can you explain please

Comment: Sure, I also just added a `return random()`  because if it goes recursive, it return nothing as the else doesn't fire and it return true inside the top of the if.  So you have to return the result of calling itself... lol sorry.  Hope that makes sense.  if it calls `random()` itself, then it returns that call which is either true, or the result of it calling itself again ( which could again be true or another result)  Without that the original call returns null, because it doesn't enter the else where the return true is located...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix i am so glad.because i have done lot of mistakes and you helped me to understand whole logic.thanks dear again.

Comment: I thought of that because it should only ever return true, as if it is not then it calls itself {n} times until it is true.  Which it then needs to return back up the stack...  So the `if(random() === true)` is somewhat pointless.

Comment: @RahulShrivastava - sure I do PHP professional sense 2007-2008. long time.